# Connect gaps between lines with plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly, scatter

I have a script that regularly updates a plotly figure and adds a scatter point. I would like a line that connects each point.
I obtain the equivalent of this code:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_scatter(x=[1],y=[2])
fig.add_scatter(x=[5],y=[4])
```

[image: noline]

while I would like the output of this code (so with a line connecting the points)

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_scatter(x=[1,5],y=[2,4])
```

[image: line]

Unfortunately I can't join `[1]` and `[5]` because I am taking the data from a file that is updated regularly.

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#lines-positioned-relative-to-the-plot--to-the-axis-data I think using this as a reference may be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to add a ***line between markers from two different traces*** since you're using:

```
fig.add_scatter(x=[1],y=[2])
fig.add_scatter(x=[5],y=[4])
```

And to my knowledge, that just won't work. Lines can only be drawn between the same points in the same trace. I'm not sure I understand why you can't store new values in a lists, but we'll leave that out of the discussion for now. The god news is that you can access the data for your `x` and `y` values in your `fig` objects through:

```
fig.data[0].x
fig.data[0].y
```

And you can append further vales to them as well. Alas not directly, since they are tuples. So you'll have to switch between lists and tuples, but that's not a very big problem.

#### First, set up your 'base' case like this:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x=[1],y=[2])
fig.show()
```

[image]

#### Then, build on the existing values in the fig` object with new values:

```
fig.data[0].x = tuple(list(fig.data[0].x) + [4])
fig.data[0].y = tuple(list(fig.data[0].y) + [5])
fig.show()
```

[image]

And as you can see, a line is automatically added between those points because they are points in the same trace.

#### Random numbers

Here's another snippet that adds random values to an existing trace in a figure:

```
fig.data[0].x = tuple(list(fig.data[0].x) + np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=1).tolist())
fig.data[0].y = tuple(list(fig.data[0].y) + np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=1).tolist())
fig.show()
```

If you run that a few times, for example in its own JupyterLab cell, you'll end up with something like this:

[image]

#### Random walk

And here's another example that takes the *last* value in your trace, and adds a random number, so you'll end up with a series in the plot below:

```
fig.data[0].x = tuple(list(fig.data[0].x) + [(list(fig.data[0].x)[-1] + 1)])
fig.data[0].y = tuple(list(fig.data[0].y) + (list(fig.data[0].y)[-1] + np.random.randint(low=-1, high=2, size=1)).tolist())
fig.show()
```

[image]

And notice that the `x-values` in this case has been set up to increase by `1` for each run as opposed to the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(x=[1, 5], y=[2, 4])
fig.show()
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have `[1,5]`, I have a loop that first reads `1` from a file and then `5`, so I can't add them at the same time

Comment: You could try creating a list and having your loop append that list after it reads each number from the file, then feed that list to the px.line function

Comment: Unfortunately for my use case this is not easily doable, the code is more complicated, I keep in memory the `fig` object and I add a scatter point every X seconds, so I was looking for something like `join_with_last_point=True`.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a empty list named `xVal` and `yVal` outside of the `px.line`, append your numbers to the list and write the actual line as `px.line(x=xVal, y=yVal)` or `fig.add_scatter(x=val, y=yVal)`

Comment: Unfortunately I add the scatter point to the plot every X seconds and I don't keep in memory the previous points, only the `fig` object. Is there a way maybe to get the last object drawn on a figure?

Comment: I believe that it is possible to remove a number in a list at a certain index (likely zero in this case) if the length of the list is greater than lets say 2 numbers, so I think that this method is possible to implement